# Ignore some letters in a postcode search. e.g Database contains DT11 but user searches DT11 0QD.

Tags: php, sql

I have the code below for a postcode search. The table in my database holds area postcode values such as [DT11] but a user will likely search a complete postcode [DT11 0QD].

How do modify the below code to ignore the extra information and display a result?

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost","user","password") or die ("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("commun91_pres128") or die ("could not find database");
$output = '';
//collect
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ps_pcsearch WHERE firstname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lastname LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search");
    $count = mysql_num_rows ($query);
    if ($count == 0){
        $output = 'there were no search results';
    }else{
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query)) {
            $a = "Your delivery day is . . . ";
            $lname = $row['lastname'];
            $id = $row ['id'];

            $output .= '<div>'.$a.' '.$lname.'</div>';  
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How do you know what is irrelevant? Anything after whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

Just use wildcards:

```
where $user_postcode like concat('%', postcode, '%')
```

Comment: Appologies, I'm very new to php, where would that be inserted in the above code?

Comment: This would go in the `select` statement, not in the php code.

Comment: Thank you. This is the 1st thing I've ever done with php / sql so I have an extremely limited knowledge of how this all works. Would I run this under the 'SQL' tab in phpMyAdmin? If so do I replace what's already there `SELECT * FROM `ps_pcsearch` WHERE 1` and then update? Also, do I need to alter what you've given if I haven't called anything 'postcode' in the table or code above? Apologies for all the basic questions but I am learning this on-the-fly!